# Повествование (обзор) от нескольких лиц в литературе (3-е лицо)

Tags: литература

Встречала комментарии и статьи о том, что, когда пишешь в третьем лице о персонажах рассказ, мысли всё равно нужно писать в каждой отдельно взятой сцене одного персонажа, остальных же описывать более поверхностно по отношению к "ведущему" и с его точки зрения. У меня же мысли персонажей скачут в каждом следующем абзаце. В одном "Маша подумала и ощутила", в уже следующем "Макс почувствовал и вспомнил". Насколько это критично? Насколько это плохо? И есть ли уже издаваемые писатели с подобным стилем написания? А то я, честно, не встречала. Сама собираюсь писать не "в стол", намерена освоить всё на должном уровне и в этом деле податься выше, потому и интересуюсь, можно ли так писать.

Пример.
Рассказ ведется от третьего лица с позиции одного только персонажа:

"Петр вошел в здание. Его нос сразу же ухватил неприятный резкий запах, а глаза забегали в поиске причины зловония. Запах напомнил ему, как когда-то, ещё в юности, он раскрыл яйцо ножом, чтобы сделать омлет, а оно оказалось протухшим. На кухне тогда воняло целый день.

Везде в здании было пусто, лишь в кабинете около входной двери два мужика явно старались что-то спрятать, дергали руками и пригибались под стол, закрывая что-то в ладошках, но разобрать, что это за вещь такая, которую вошедшему не хотели давать узнать, не представлялось возможным. Петра это неведение даже немного пугало."

А вот так примерно пишу я:

"Петр вошел в здание, сразу же учуяв какой-то странный неприятный запах. Он начал озираться по сторонам и искать причину зловония. Запах напомнил ему, как когда-то, ещё в юности, он раскрыл яйцо ножом, чтобы сделать омлет, а оно оказалось протухшим. На кухне тогда воняло целый день.

Мужчина в костюме - Янг - услышал, как кто-то вошел и сразу толкнул локтем приятеля, успевшего задремать. А после начал искать место, где спрятать маленький пистолет. Он сам не понимал, зачем прячет игрушку, но отчего-то продолжал - уж больно он не хотел показывать ещё кому-то постороннему своё творение, оно ассоциировалось у него с чем-то очень сокровенным, особенным. Да и напарник уже и сам увлеченно с Янгом вместе искал укромное место.

Петра озадачили действия мужиков, но он так и не усмотрел, что же они пытались спрятать. Его это неведение даже немного пугало."

Comment: С ходу: 1. "Петра это неведение даже немного пугало."  2. "Его это неведение даже немного пугало."  Точка ставится _**после**_ кавычек.

Comment: Спасибо, учту, но можно ответ по вопросу, пожалуйста?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но, как мне кажется, не вписывается в рамки этого сайта. Напомню, что написано в Справке. *На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы? «Русский язык» — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка. Мы приветствуем вопросы, связанные с различными разделами языкознания (будь то орфография или пунктуация, синтаксис или грамматика, этимология или лексика), о его истории и современном состоянии.* (rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Метка "литература" тут есть. Не думаю, что прям нельзя подобного рода вопросы задавать. Я же не спрашиваю на русском форуме, как строится отрицание в английском языке в настоящем времени, тем более, не спрашиваю, чему равен синус числа пи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И есть ли уже издаваемые писатели с подобным стилем написания? А то я,
>   честно, не встречала.

Я тоже не встречал таких писателей. Разве что у детских писателей перенос авторской точки зрения встречается чаще, но и там это локализовано в отдельных эпизодах, как я примерно помню.

Иногда такой стиль используется нарочито, но только с определённой целью. В анекдотах, например.

> "Интересно, куда он идет", — подумал Мюллер. "Не твое дело", — подумал
>   Штирлиц.

Из предложенных Вами двух вариантов описания ситуации второй явно хуже, я считаю.

**Дополнение**.
Что-то подобное можно найти у Филипа К. Дика. В тех книгах, в которых главные герои страдают раздвоением личности, или же рассказ ведётся от имени таких героев. Для примера можно вспомнить "Помутнение". В этом романе полицейский (главный герой) внедряется как агент в среду наркоманов и становится одним из них (другим главным героем). Со временем эти герои перестают понимать, что они — один и тот же человек. У Дика много такого, читать это безумно интересно, но на любителя.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, есть такой прием, но он **нестандартный**, и пользоваться им надо умело. Читатель должен ясно осознавать, что **ему предлагаются  точки зрения разных героев** и что это не стилистическая погрешность, а так задумано автором. В любом случае, как мне кажется,  это должен быть текст определенного объема, а не каждый абзац.

В приведенном же примере такое **перескакивание из абзаца в абзац не кажется оправданным, выглядит странно.** Художественности тексту оно не добавляет, а вот утомительным показаться может.